# Importing large xml dataset into symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony

I have a fairly large xml file - 7G - to import into a symfony2 app, storing in mongodb.

Are there any symfony2 components, or preferred ways to do this?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php won't help? In any cases there 2 ways, first is load at once (server can die) this file (because of 7G) and second one somehow divide xml file for several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `XMLReader` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php .

As far as I know `XMLReader` streams the file rather than reading the whole file in before doing anything with it.

From there you can convert it to a `simplexml` object if you would prefer it like http://posterous.richardcunningham.co.uk/using-a-hybrid-of-xmlreader-and-simplexml

Not sure about a Symfony specific component though.